# WIX Bundle Creation

Tags: wix

I tried to create an MSI which is having and exe in it. Used the Bundle option in WIX. While doing that getting an error. Can somebody help me fix this issue. Below is the code:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"  
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="7AE2E358-B5A0-44B1-9B29-FDD275992993">
    <Chain>
      <ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" 
                  SourceFile="ca\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"              
                  DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164193"            
                  DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)" />
    </Chain>
 </Bundle>
```

**Error**

> error LGHT0089: Multiple entry sections '{A1B42CCE-8AFE-11E2-AC8C-B3456288709B}' and '{8E644424-3113-462E-9197-32DF740AEB78}' found.  Only one entry section may be present in a single target.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WiX bundle for installing .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360163/wix-bundle-for-installing-net)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That error indicates that your project is building with files that contain more than one of these elements: `Product`, `Module`, `Patch`, `PatchCreation`, `Bundle`. In your case, it sounds like you added a file with a `Bundle` element to a project that already had a `Product` element. That isn't supported in the WiX toolset today. You need to put the `Bundle` element in a separate project.

Thus, when creating a bootstrapper and MSI, you'll have two .wixproj files. The first .wixproj will contain your `Product` information. The second .wixproj will contain your `Bundle` information and have a project reference to the first .wixproj so that the build order is correct.

Comment: How is the bundle project run ?