# WiX bundle for installing .NET

Tags: .net, wix

I'm trying to create a bundle for installing .NET Framework 4.0 if it needs to be installed. I realize there are similar questions, but all of the answers are just snippets and don't describe what file they go in, and how they're imported in to the .wxs file.

This is what I have in a Bundle.wxs file. I get compiler warnings about multiple entry sections.

Error   2   Multiple entry sections '{CF06625F-7B6B-4B6E-A24E-FDDCA7CFFFF4}' and '{0D1EE60A-FC4F-4083-8B1E-311E75A67B4C}' found.  Only one entry section may be present in a single target.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Bundle UpgradeCode="{C6FF478E-C3DA-4D78-929D-24C3F3307356}" Version="4.0">
    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Most of the links on the WiX page are broken, and do not mention anything about attributes to use on the Bundle tag, and seem to interchange the Package/Product. I could not find mention on the Wix pages about setting a GUID for Bundles. Is that something new to Wix 3.7?

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm

1. How do I use the predefined .NET 4.0 PackageGroupRef/PayloadGroupRef
2. Does it have to be in Bundle.wxs? Where does it get imported in to my main Product.wxs?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That error indicates that your project is building with files that contain more than one of these elements: `Product`, `Module`, `Patch`, `PatchCreation`, `Bundle`. In your case, it sounds like you added a file with a `Bundle` element to a project that already had a `Product` element. That isn't supported in the WiX toolset today. You need to put the `Bundle` element in a separate project.

Thus, when creating a bootstrapper and MSI, you'll have two .wixproj files. The first .wixproj will contain your `Product` information. The second .wixproj will contain your `Bundle` information and have a project reference to the first .wixproj so that the build order is correct.

Comment: Ok, so I'll create a sepetate proj for my bundle. And a single bundle can have a chain of multiple installers, right? My chain could have .NET 3.5, .NET 4.0, SQL Server installer, etc.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `Bundle` is a `collection of packages`.

Comment: +1 - Couldn't find any reference/info on the requirement of having to reference/create 2 Wix projects.

Answer (score 10):

The `Wix/Bundle` element is the root of a Bootstrapper project. It doesn't go in the same project as your Product.wxs. In Visual Studio, there is a template for new Wix Bootstrapper projects. You probably haven't created one.

Then in your bundle's Chain, you'll want .NET and your application's MSI, as in the example. To use the NetFx40Web, you have to reference WixNetfxExtension. Wix projects that reference other Wix projects have predefined variables so you can use their properties such as TargetPath. The example assumes this Bootstrapper project references a Setup project called MyApplicationSetup.

```
<Chain>
    <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web"/>
    <MsiPackage Id="MyApplication" SourceFile="$(var.MyApplicationSetup.TargetPath)"/>
</Chain>
```

Comment: Yes, I did not use VS's Bootstrapper proj, nor was I aware of it.

I assume MsiPackage Id is referring to the Package ID of my main installer project? I am confused on this because my Package doesn't have an ID, nor a reference to Msi.

Comment: I created my proj with a Bundle file as you have above, except I wanted to use "NetFx40Redist" as the package ref. The EXE was built, but It's about 1 MB. I would expect it to have the .NET 4 setup file adjacent to it, as is done in Visual Studio Deployment Projects. I'm not certain if it actually pulled that package.

Comment: The WiX Toolset schema is wonderfully consistent: Id attributes give unique names to elements, which can be referenced by element with names ending in Ref. So, the MsiPackage Id is an arbitrary name you give to the package pointed to by SourceFile. In the context of a bootstrapper, "package" refers to any sort of installer and "msi" is a nick-name for a Windows Installer package. Your WiX Setup project creates an msi file.

Comment: The package group "NetFx40Redist" is authored to download the needed files at install time. That's why you don't see them in your build output.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. This Wix site implies that Redist is the full standalone setup, as opposed to the Web which is for the web installer.
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm

Comment: What I don't understand is, when I build my bootstrapper project, referencing a NetFx package group, and my MSI, it builds, but the output bin for my boostrapper project contains only the loose files to be installed, but not the MSI and not a NET FX installer executable.

Comment: @StealthRabbi the output will contain the bootstrapper and loose files, which is all you need to deploy. It won't contain files for packages that are compressed (meaning they are stored inside the bootstrapper) nor those that are downloaded at install-time.

Comment: @TomBlodget Can you explain what is **MyApplicationSetup** in **SourceFile="$(var.MyApplicationSetup.TargetPath)"** expression? It is id or name of what exactly? You talk about project referencing. How 2 projects should be compiled: together or one-by-one?

Comment: @Boris MyApplicationSetup is the name of the WiX Setup project (one with a Product.wxs file). See [Project References](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html), which also apply to when a bootstrapper project references a setup project.

Comment: That page talks about some GUI. Is it possible to do this without it?

Comment: Yes. Everything in WiX is done with command-line tools and .wsx, .wsl, etc files. If you want to take it up a level, you can use a .wixproj MSBuild project file that imports WiX targets (provided by the WiX installation). That is the level of project references and the variables defined from them. If you want a GUI for a .wixproj, you use Visual Studio (non-Express) or [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx). Msbuild.exe builds any msbuild project on the command line. (Set the verbosity level higher if you want to see the WiX command-line tools being called.)