# How to bundle dependency .dll files with main product in WiX

Tags: .net, wix, 64-bit

I am creating a wix installer for a .NET project with many dependencies. Currently, I have a working .msi installer, but as expected all the dependency .dll's (as well as a resources folder) are placed in the same directory as the installed application rather than being bundled with it.

Reading the answer to [WIX Bundle Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295443/wix-bundle-creation), it seems possible to keep my Product as is in one file and have another file with a Bundle referencing this product, but I cannot seem to find any examples of this.

Is there a simple way to do this? I've included the outline of the product code below.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:ui="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UIExtension">  
    <Product Id="*" Name="#####" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="..." UpgradeCode="...">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64"/>

    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

        <MajorUpgrade AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="alphaInstaller" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductMenuComponents" />
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="DependencyComponents"/>
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ResourcesComponents"/>
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
         <Directory Id="ProgramMenu64Folder">
            ...
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
          <Component Id="CMP_alphaGUISetup" Win64="yes">
             <File Id="FILE_alphaGUIApplication.exe" Source="$(var.alphaGUI.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"></File>
          </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductMenuComponents" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="..." >
        <Shortcut .../>
        <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue .../>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
    <ComponentGroup Id="DependencyComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Source=...>
      <Component Id="log4net">
        <File Name="log4net.dll" />
      </Component>
        ...
    </ComponentGroup>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ResourcesComponents" Directory="ResourcesFolder" Source=...>
      <Component Id="logo.ico">
        ...
    </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: so you have an MSI now but the Files that are part of the MSI is not packaged into a single file - is that the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Isaiah4110 Yes, exactly. It's also ok if the final bundle is not an MSI but rather an EXE or anything similar.

Comment: let me know if the below suggestion worked.

Comment: Hi Theo, updated my answer slightly. Nothing revolutionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Single-file-deployment?***: I am a little unsure if this is what you ask, but it seems you want to embed all dlls within a single .NET executable file?

---

***Ilmerge.exe***: *This is not my area of expertise*, but there is this answer: [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable) that you can check out. The tool [**Ilmerge.exe**](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) - [how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079242/129130) (also see answer below). Mock-up:

```
ILMerge.exe /target:winexe /out:All.exe Main.exe one.dll two.dll
```

I have never used this. I would be very surprised if it worked for all cases. Obviously. Worth a try? Test merged binary using [virustotal.com](https://virustotal.com) (release mode binary) to determine if you trigger any malware warnings.

***Resource File Embedding***: You can also embed resource files such as images, html templates and other things within a .NET executable, if that is what you want. Just the tersest mock-up I could find ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42794564/129130)):

- ***Add file*** `TestFile.txt` as embedded resource: `Project Menu` <kbd>>></kbd> `Properties` <kbd>>></kbd> `Resources` <kbd>>></kbd> `Add Existing file`.
- ***Code*** access: `string queryFromResourceFile = Properties.Resources.Testfile.ToString();`

***Shared Project***: There is the elusive "[*Shared Project*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634753/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shared-project-and-a-class-library-in-visual-st)" for .NET projects / C# type that gets compiled into your main executable at build time. Not sure when this project type came along. It is present in VS2017.

***Single Project Option***: You could also obviously move all code files into the same project and compile an executable that way. I wouldn't do this unless you intend to keep all source files in one project permanently. Otherwise you get a very silly build process? I guess all options should be mentioned, so we remember or acknowledge why they are bad.

***Further Options?***: I am sure there are further options. Probably some flags for the compiler that I am unaware of. Please add if you know of any. [Found this somewhat crazy approach on youtube](https://youtu.be/x-KK7bmo1AM?t=179) (setting dll resources to be embedded inside the Visual Studio project, and then add code to read the embedded assembly). I wonder how anti-virus software judges the latter? Test using [virustotal.com](https://virustotal.com) (release mode binary). Same goes for binaries merged with Ilmerge.exe I guess.

---

***Links***:

- [How to merge multiple assemblies into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one)
- [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)

Answer (score 0):

Please add the [Media Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/media.html) to your WXS file right below the package element and that should fix it.

```
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="simple.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
```

Comment: Won't this have the same effect as the `<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>`? The .cab file is already packed with the installer, the problem is once the installer runs all the .dll's are not bundled.

Comment: I missed that in your code, as it was underneath the upgrade elements. But yes, if you are using wix3.8 or above it should have the same effect.

Comment: I don't understand - once the installer runs what do you mean by DLL's are not bundled?

Comment: In the install directory, I get the application .exe and a bunch of .dll's together, ideally I would like it to just be one single .exe file with all the dependencies included in it.

Comment: Looks like you have a basic misunderstanding of what MSI does. MSI is just a packager of the things that you tell it to package, and then it will deploy those files. Basically consider MSI as a zip file, it will zip up all the files that you ask it to and then unzip them at the target location.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using a different framework?

Comment: It's outside of the MSI functionality - you are asking for a .net application to package all the dependent DLL's inside the EXE. I don't think .net supports that.